# How to use parseInt to add intergers and also concatenate a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following code:

```
if (ev.data.type === "height") {
  if (ev.data.form === src) {
    setHeight(ev.data.message + "px");
  }
}
```

By default it adds height 1900px and now I want to add additional 10px so it became 1910px How I can achieve this using parseInt and so I can modify my above syntax?

Comment: You can use Number().
setHeight((Number(ev.data.message) + 10) + 'px');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ev.data.message` is a string that's coercable to a Number type, then this will work:

```
setHeight((parseInt(ev.data.message, 10) + 10) + "px");
```

More information on `parseInt()` is available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: it looks good and what If I want to add extra 40px so my code will be like below?
setHeight((parseInt(ev.data.message, 50) + 50) + "px")
can you confirm pls?

Comment: To add an extra 40 then the code would be this: `setHeight((parseInt(ev.data.message, 10) + 50) + "px");`. Note that the first `10` value is the `radix` property of the `parseInt()` call and isn't related to the addition operation

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (ev.data.type === "height") {
  if (ev.data.form === src) {
    const msg = parseInt(ev.data.message, 10);
    if (typeof msg === "number" && msg !== NaN) {
      setHeight(msg + 10 + "px");
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly transform the message to the int, and check the type and value.
If it's ok, go ahead to set new height.

Check the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) out in the MDN

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (ev.data.type === "height") {
  if (ev.data.form === src) {
    const currentHeight = parseInt(ev.data.message); // it parsing the current height 
    const updatedHeight = currentHeight + 10; // adding 10 to the parsed height value
    setHeight(updatedHeight + "px"); // Concatenating "px" to the updated height value
  }
}
```